# Is there a way to upload a file to a bot from the emulator using adaptive cards in bot framework

Tags: c#, botframework

I am trying to take inputs from user through an adaptive card , in addition to which I want the user to upload a file as well in the same adaptive card . 
Can somebody help me with the code to do the same . I found the code to attach files with hardcoded URLs. Is there a way from emulator to open and select a file from file explorer?

Answer (score 0):

As of now, there is no such provision of uploading a file in adaptive Cards. The supported  action types are **Action.OpenUrl, Action.Submit, Action.ShowCard, Action.ToggleVisibility**. As per a [comment](https://github.com/microsoft/AdaptiveCards/issues/3708#issuecomment-572707985) on [this](https://github.com/microsoft/AdaptiveCards/issues/2384) GitHub issue which is similar to your question, **it's not currently on the roadmap**. However, depending on the type of channel you are using, for example webchat, you can make custom modifications to enable file upload from an adaptive card. Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55269415/prompt-user-to-upload-file-in-dialog-flow-with-ms-bot-framwork-v4/55408977#55408977) implementation for the same. If you are using MS Teams, then the manifest needs to have **supportsFiles: true**.

If you need support for file upload, I would suggest you to create a new feature request in the Adaptive Cards [repo](https://github.com/microsoft/AdaptiveCards/issues).

Hope this helps.